# Why is Rust code completion not working in my Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, rust

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 v14 with VisualRust 0.1.2

Under `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Visual Rust` statement completion is greyed out and cannot be enabled.

Under `Tools -> Options -> Visual Rust` I have selected `Use bundled racer` and `Read rust sources from environment variable`

The racer that came bundled with VisualRust works correctly when called manually, that is `racer-120e98b.exe complete std::io::` returns the relevant results.

In Visual Studio, writing `let e = std::io::` and then pressing `CTRL + Space` to trigger autocompletion will only return a list of the reserved keywords (such as if, while, struct, etc).

I'm guessing that the problem is that statement completion can't be turned on. How do I solve this?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, I don't suppose you ever found the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I run Visual Studio 2015 Community, and this is how I did it:

Download the racer and the rust sources via

```
cargo install racer
rustup component add rust-src
```

However, the `RUST_SRC_PATH` variable is not yet set, and I do not know who is supposed to set it. The following batch script will set the variable to its correct value, see [this issue on github](https://github.com/phildawes/racer/issues/595).

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%P IN (`rustc --print sysroot`) DO SET RS=%%P
SETX RUST_SRC_PATH "%RS%\lib\rustlib\src\rust\src"
```

After this, I still had to specify the path to `racer.exe` manually instead of the `Use bundled racer` option. By default, you can find it here:

```
%USERPROFILE%\.cargo\bin\racer.exe
```

Hope it helps!